# Matplotlib: Boxplot outlier color change if keyword sym is used

Tags: python, matplotlib

Applies only to Matplotlib <1.4.0!

I have the strange effect, that the color of the outlier changes, if i change the symbol used to draw them. ([Documentation for Boxplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot)) Seems to me like a bug.

How can i 'reset' the colour to blue for all outlier even if i want to use another symbol than "+"?

Minimal Working Example modeled after [official Example](http://matplotlib.org/pyplots/boxplot_demo.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pylab import *

# fake up some data
spread = rand(50) * 100
center = ones(25) * 50
flier_high = rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = rand(10) * -100
data = concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# Left Figure
boxplot(data)

# Right Figure
figure()
boxplot(data, sym='.')
```

[image]

Comment: This code does not generate this figure, I get two windows...

Comment: True, i copied them in one Picture.

Comment: Don't do that, it makes understanding your problem a lot harder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like BrenBarn and Joop correctly pointed out, it's easiest to just specify a color with a character: `boxplot(data, sym='b.')` to reset the color to blue or `sym='gx'` for green x's in the plot.

With the Help of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238357/finding-the-outlier-points-from-matplotlib-boxplot?rq=1) is was able to find a way to make the outlier fully customizable. (I want to reduce the size of the outlier)

```
# insert this after lines '#Right figure', 'figure()'

r = boxplot(data, sym="w") # outlier are computed but not drawn

top_points = r["fliers"][0].get_data()[1]
bottom_points = r["fliers"][2].get_data()[1]
plot(np.ones(len(top_points)), top_points, "x", color="blue", markersize=1)
plot(np.ones(len(bottom_points)), bottom_points, ".", color="blue")
#if you have several boxplots this "np.ones(len(bottom_points))" is the number of plot you want to draw in, so 1s for the first [2,2,2,2,...] for the second ect.
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the flier _are_ drawn, they are just white so you can't see them.

Comment: It might be. i tried "w." before and had white spots on the whiskers and here they are gone, that might just be because of the smaller default element.

Answer (score 2):

looking at the defaults for boxplot sym:

```
*sym* : [ default 'b+' ]  # blue +
```

so the default is a blue +   if you specify just a point it can have different color.  Could probably think of situations where this behavior is desired.   Could probably be described as inconsistent defaults, but not a bug.

so it is not a bug if you want two plots with same color use:

```
boxplot(data, sym='+')
boxplot(data, sym='.')
```

without specifying the colour it seems to rotate (desired behaviour if in some cases).   if you want to stick to fixed color use sym='b+'  and sym='b.'

Comment: I still consider this a bug if it's not documented to do that (which it isn't).  Using different colors for high and low outliers is not standard boxplot practice, let alone switching color on every outlier group.

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed strange.  You can work around it by specifying the color on the symbol.  Use `boxplot(data, sym='b.')` (b for blue).  However, it looks like a bug to me, especialyl since the odd color only shows up on the lower outliers, not the upper ones.

Comment: The color changes for every group of outlier, if you plot two boxplots next to each other the outlier colors are (blue, green) for the first boxplot and (red, turqouise) for the second.

Answer (score 1):

What is going on here is that the way the flier are drawn is using a cal to `plot` (see the `doplot` helper function defined inside `boxplot`).  If you do not pass a color in via `sym` the plot functions do the default thing which is to color cycle following the `axes` cycle.

For 1.4.0 (we have a release candidate out, you should all test it!) the code under `boxplot` has been completely re-written.  This exposed a bug (which will be patched shortly) and will work as expected.